# ASP.NET server side tags vs. JavaScript-based UI and REST

Tags: .net, asp.net, javascript, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I've been developing "traditional" ASP.NET applications with server side ASP.NET controls and code behind files, etc. Now I'm exploring several JavaScript libraries like: jQuery, YUI, Ext Js, Prototype. (also it's hard to pick one, but it's another post). All these libraries make client to server communication a lot easier, but they also offer nice set of very sleek UI controls. And some controls are way sleeker than ASP.NET server side controls in my opinion.

But now I am questioning the traditional ASP.NET model. I am leaning towards all HTML/JS UI talking to the server (just a simple aspx page) via REST.
What do you think? Have anyone used this approach? What are some drawbacks and gotchas? Also if you could comment on what JS Library/Framework you used and your experience with it, that would be great too.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a very lengthy topic covered by numerous people, but at its core the difference is basically this:

For **very form-heavy web applications, which maintain a great deal of state information**; frequently stay on the same page and behave similarly to a desktop application, **the traditional ASP.NET WebForms model** provides a lot of the glue to hold all that together for you.

For **everything else**, the **REST/MVC model** works best.

This is a generalization and does not apply to every single situation, but on the whole it's a good rule of thumb.

It's also very important to point out that if you don't have a captive audience (such as a corporate intranet, and sometimes even then) you should code your site, WebForms *or* REST, to work without JS. Then go back and add the sweet goodness for those who can support it.

Comment: I'm convinced that if the non-JS approach takes longer, go with JS right at the outset (especially for authenticated users.)  People without JS are used to the internet being broken.

Comment: @Iconic which is the first thing we fix when the site doesn't has good search engine rankings ...

Comment: I should have said "only for authenticated users".

Comment: @iconic the non-JS approach only takes longer if you "code for both". It's remarkable how ultra-semantic, functional XHTML lends itself to JS manipulation :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't rule out a hybrid model. ASP.NET now supports server controls that natively output javascript to the browser.  If you have traditional controls that render markup and use the ASP.NET WebForms model for posting data, consider modifying the controls to be ScriptControls, which allows you to handle loading data, etc. in your existing codebehind, but write javascript to handle the UI of the control entirely.  You can write server controls that output the javascript you need (and set variable values, etc. with data from your codebehind during load), and then instead of doing postbacks, have your javascript communicate with a web service using AJAX.  Definitely explore ajax.asp.net.

Answer (score 0):

If the browser doesn't support JS you will block the user out completely. Also, you will probably run into an issue with some search engines. Notice that I say this because you are thinking about hitting a single URL on the browser, and then using only JS for the rest. The same goes for having it all in flash and Silverlight for that matter. Any of those work nice for private info, or features that aren't meant to go in the search engines, but for the rest of the info, you really want different URLs.

That said: ASP.NET isn't so good at preventing the no-js issues. Even the default paging for the grids as that issue - I got a site from a handful entry in google to 2800+. The  http://asp.net/mvc is better at making it clear with what you are working with.

Comment: users that are on browsers that don't support js will have problems using regular asp.net pages (which make quite extensive use of js) and pretty much the rest of the internet.
Also I don't see why you couldn't make js-based ui search engines friendly

Comment: @WebMatrix the only way for a JS-based UI to be search-engine-friendly is to function properly without the JS. And you're ignoring screen readers and other handicapped-assistance software, which doesn't support JS. It's easy to make ASP.NET work without JS, just requires being not lazy.

Comment: Agreed rex, asp.net hides it and uses some awful defaults in many places though :( ... but every asp.net  dev needs to be aware of those. Now that you mentioned screen readers and related software, I think in some applications/organizations/places it even be illegal not to comply with those.